# How to add non-standard library in C++?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, shared-libraries, static-libraries

How do I add a non-standard library in C++ so that I can just add it like a standard library without having to link with a -I option in my makefile?

The problem occurs because I am developing code on multiple servers and with different absolute path directories.  I am using the Eigen C++ library and can get it working while calling up the following command in the makefile "-I /usr/local/include/eigen/ -c norm.cpp constants.cpp". The problem occurs when I transfer the server the absolute path is not the same an I have to change it each time I compile.  I know I could give it an absolute path but since I use this library a lot I don't want to create strange relative path names.

I am using gcc and have tried placing the eigen folder in /usr/include/c++/4.5, /usr/include/c++/4.5.2 and /usr/local/include/ but it still doesn't work. I am currently using Ubuntu 11.04.

How do I find the standard library that gcc searches in and how do I add a non-standard library so I can include it like "#include ".

Answer (score 3):

GCC by default looks in the following directory:

```
/usr/local/include/
/usr/include/
```

you can control the gcc search path by editing the following shell variables :

```
$ C_INCLUDE_PATH=/the/new/include/path 
$ export C_INCLUDE_PATH
```

for C++:

```
$ CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/the/path/to/search 
$ export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

You can do the same for the library path :

```
$ LIBRARY_PATH=/the/path/whatever
$ export LIBRARY_PATH
```

I hope that gives you the answer. :)

Comment: That gets the header but not the library itself.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ranlib](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ranlib) and [libtool](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/).